# Editor customization: how to change color of boolean keywords?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, customization

I am trying to adjust the appearance of the editor.

Using the *"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"* and *"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations"* settings, I have managed to make all of the desired adjustments, except for the **true/false** keywords.

Search as I might, I cannot find the setting which controls the appearance of these keywords. Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to change the color of both true and false:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[<THEME_NAME>]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "constant.language",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "<COLOR_CODE>"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```